# Generate all possible permutations of stenography keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, permutation

Apologies in advance, because I understand roughly nothing of what goes on here, but this seemed to be the place to ask...

I'm hoping to generate all possible single simultaneous strokes from a stenography keyboard:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenotype#Keyboard_layout

The stenography keyboard contains 23 keys - the main 22:

```
STKPWHRAO*EUFRPBLGTSDZ
```

If none of the AO*EU keys are included, a hyphen is used in their place, so all permutations of this sequence is also necessary:

```
STKPWHR-FRPBLGTSDZ
```

The 23rd key is the number bar, which changes some of the keys, so permutations of these, although separate, would also help:

```
#12K3W4RAT50*EU6R7B8G9SDZ
#12K3W4R-6R7B8G9SDZ
```

In a single simultaneous key stroke, any keys will always be recognised in the above order; they're either selected or ignored. For example, if "Z" is included, it will always be the last key of any permutation. I'm trying to generate all potential permutations, including those of individual keys.

The hyphen or asterisk in the middle of the keyboard helps differentiate between keys that are on both sides of the keyboard (S, T, P, R). For individual keys, for example, you'd list "T-" for the one on the left of the keyboard and "-T" for the one on the right of the keyboard. The entire left bank of the keyboard would be "STKPWHR-"; the entire right bank would be "-FRPBLGTSDZ".

I naively assume there's a simple way to generate this online, but ... I've been wrong before. From what I've been able to find, the main obstacle seems to be keeping the characters in sequential order. I can easily remove any duplicates, of which there would be many from the four sequences.

Even the permutations involving up to 10 keys of the 23 would be a huge help; it would be very rare that 15 or more keys would ever be used at the same time.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What output are you looking for, a text file with all the combinations? Do you want to consider "impossible" combinations (allowing the Philly shift of -SD, -TZ?)  


Or do you just want counts/statistics based off of the number of combinations you can make with each side and stuff like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a script in Python that will generate the combinations of steno order like you wanted. Some notes:

- This is similar to some [Plover](https://github.com/openstenoproject/plover) code, which is also written in Python.
- This code will generate chords with impossible combinations (unless you use a Philly shift, e.g. -SD, -TZ, -TSD, -SDZ, etc.)
- I included the number bar output as well.

There are a lot of combinations…with chords ranging from 1 to 10 keys I got 1,698,159 results. For 1 to 23, there are 8,388,606 possible chords.

[Here are the possible chords with 1 to 10 keys](https://gist.github.com/morinted/dfeecef6b7e4a9a5f77f50bcf28d61f4) (note that this page will load slowly due to the large amount of data).

And here is the script that I used to generate this file:

```py
from itertools import combinations
steno_order = (
    '#', 'S-', 'T-', 'K-', 'P-', 'W-', 'H-', 'R-',
    'A', 'O', '*', 'E', 'U',
    '-F', '-R', '-P', '-B', '-L', '-G', '-T', '-S', '-D', '-Z',
)
steno_to_number ={
    'S-': '1-',
    'T-': '2-',
    'P-': '3-',
    'H-': '4-',
    'A': '5',
    'O': '0',
    '-F': '-6',
    '-P': '-7',
    '-L': '-8',
    '-T': '-9',
}

def combinations_of_steno_order(min_keys, max_keys):
    assert min_keys < max_keys, 'Chord size must increase'
    for i in range(min_keys, max_keys):
        for chord in combinations(steno_order, i):
            shortform = ''
            add_hyphen = True
            if chord[0] == '#':
                # Convert to numbers if number bar is pressed.
                chord = [steno_to_number.get(steno_key, steno_key) for steno_key in chord]
            for steno_key in chord:
                if steno_key == '#':
                    shortform += steno_key
                elif steno_key[-1] == '-':
                    # Left-hand
                    shortform += steno_key[0]
                elif steno_key[0] == '-':
                    # Right-hand
                    if add_hyphen:
                        shortform += '-'
                        add_hyphen = False
                    shortform += steno_key[1]
                else:
                    # Center key
                    add_hyphen = False
                    shortform += steno_key
            yield shortform

print('\n'.join(list(combinations_of_steno_order(1, 10))))
```

Comment: This is pretty much the most impressive thing I've ever seen in my life. Can we recommend knighthoods via answers here?

To answer your questions, this was intended for practical use - basically as a backup for any single strokes that weren't already defined.

Can't thank you enough!

Comment:  no problem Bruce. The best way to award an answer is by "accepting" it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers